# Why aren't positive ions emitted at the same rate as electrons via thermionic emission?

Tags: atomic-physics, evaporation, ions

The [Effective Work Functions of the Elements](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.progsurf.2020.100583) are very similar for removing an electron or a positive ion, e.g. about 4.5 eV for Tungsten.
If their work functions are similar, why aren't positive ions emitted via thermionic emission at a similar rate to electrons when a metal wire is heated?

Adding to my confusion, according to [Richardson's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission#Richardson%27s_law), the thermionic emission rate for electrons is proportional to the electron mass.
This naively suggests that very massive positive ions should be emitted more often, not less, which is clearly very, very wrong.
Instead, thermal emission of ions seems to be an evaporative process depending on the thermionic work function, the ionizing potential, and the latent heat of evaporation of the metal, with [evaporative rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz%E2%80%93Knudsen_equation#Non-dissociative_adsorption_(Langmuirian_adsorption)) $\propto 1/\sqrt{M_{ion}}$. (See, for example, Smith's 1930 article on ["The Emission of Positive Ions From Tungsten and Molybdenum"](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.35.381).)

I've always assumed that the difference is due to interatomic forces creating a much higher potential barrier for an ion (or atom) to escape, even though the ultimate net energy requirement (i.e. the work function) is similar to that needed to remove an electron. I can't, however, immediately find a clear discussion that either confirms this or provides the correct explanation.

My apologies that I couldn't find unpaywalled alternatives for the cited papers.

Comment: Enthalpy of vaporization for tungsten is 774 kJ/mol, or just over 8 eV/atom

Comment: As the mass of an ion is much larger then the mass of an electron, the velocity they  acquire to distance from the surface must be much smaller than the velocity of the electrons of same energy, so the ions would stay on the surface studied.

Comment: @anna-v Yes, I also wondered if the ions are so slow they are more likely to be recaptured, but Smith's article discusses how the reflection coefficient is likely to be small.

Comment: @Jon-Custer Good point, since 8 eV vs 4.5 eV makes a big difference in $e^{-W/kT}$ since $kT$ is only a fraction of an electron volt for red-hot metal, but this makes me wonder what is the relationship between the positive ion work function quoted in the tables and the vaporization enthalpy. I think the positive ion work functions are measured by [secondary_ion_mass_spectrometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_ion_mass_spectrometry).